Proving Conjugacy of Isomorphic Finite Reflection Groups via an Isometry in Orthogonal Group $ O(V) $
Let $ W_1 \text{ and } W_2 $ be finite reflection group acting on the euclidean space $ V $. If there exists an isomorphism between $ W_1 \text{ and } W_2 $ induced by the isometry $\varphi $  of $ V $, then $ W_1 \text{ and } W_2  $ are conjugate in $ O(V) $. This is to say that $ \varphi w_1 \varphi ^{-1} \in W_2 $.
Geometrically it is clear that, if you apply an isometry (say rotation) and then a reflection, then you just get another reflection. But how do I prove this mathematically?

Geometrically is mathematically so I suspect you mean you can see it intuitively or in examples. If you want to convince yourself more rigourously ask yourself what makes a transformation a reflection and then you can see that is preserved under conjugation by elements of $O(V)$.
